# what is segmentation fault (core dumped) and how to fix it?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make K&R 2 exercise 1-20. Everything compiles though whenever I give it a input it gives me a **segmentation fault (core dumped)**. I don't know what this means, whats causing it and how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define TAB 4

int main()
{
  int c, i, j;  /*len is the length of the line; i & j is for for loops*/

  char line[MAXLINE];             /*Line input*/

  while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
      printf("%s", line);
      }else{
        if (c == '\t'){
          for (j=0;j<TAB+1;++j){
            line[i+j] = ' ';
          }
        }else{
      line[i] = c;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: To answer your question title: [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806)

Comment: Hi. I compiled your code and am not able to replicate your issue. Code compiles fine and i dont get any runtime errors either.

Comment: @JakobSachs do you get some warning about using variable without initialization?

Comment: Did you try searching google for 'segmentation fault'?

Comment: You  might look at this somment a bit closer "i & j is for for loops". Is that true? How many `for` loops do you see?

Comment: @Gerhardh No, but i also didnt use any compiler warnings. Just quickly threwthe code into onlinegdb.com

Comment: @JakobSachs that would be the important part. ;) "Works on my machine" only points towards undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Gerhardh True, all i wanted was OP to supply more information and improve his post.

Comment: That is a good time to learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Step through your code and carefully whatch your variables.

Comment: What is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: `line` is also not initialized and never given a null terminator, so the `printf` is also UB.

Answer (score -2):

Ok so you get this error segmentation fault when you are touching the memory which
you shouldn't

for example
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[2];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 5;

    for (int i = 10000000 ; i < 10000001; i++)
   {
    printf("%i",a[i]);
   }
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Comment: could you point out what memory in the code I'm touching that is causing it?

Comment: "you get this error segmentation fault when you are touching the memory which you shouldn't" Nope, not realiably. Only if you get lucky.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Showing an example of how to maye provoke a segfault does not answer OPs question.